# Is flying over Har Habayis allowed?

Tags: halacha, beis-hamikdash, travel, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

It is my understanding that one is forbidden to go onto the Har Habayit ("Temple Mount") while s/he is Tamei.

However, if one is only over Har Habayit but not physically on the ground (e.g. flying in an Airplane or Helicopter), does that fall into the same categorical prohibition? Or does one have to be physically on the ground?

Comment: Why would you think it's different? In general, an enclosed space that's unroofed is considered to extend all the way upwards.

Comment: @DonielF That's news to me. Who said that is in terms of all halachos?

Comment: It's true by tumah v'taharah. You need a one-tefach roof to block tumah from going in or out. I suppose you could ask if the floor of the airplane could count.

Comment: @DonielF I understand that you are referring to *tumah* going in and out. I don't understand how that relates to the prohibition for being on Har Habayit.

Comment: What's the reason for the prohibition of being on Har HaBayis? One who is tamei is not allowed to be on Har HaBayis. If there's a tefach separation, the tumah is not on Har HaBayis.

Comment: In his work Yabia Omer (Yore Deah 5:26) Rav Ovadia Yosef argues that it is forbidden.

Comment: The point is to include motivation; why do you think it might be similar.

Comment: @mevaqesh Once again, I believe this is precisely what I am asking. As I explain in the question, we're not allowed to go onto Har Habayit - which is my premise. My precise question is "does this extend to flying or not". I am still not sure of what you would like me to add.

Comment: There are some who say that being 3 Tefachim above ground is not considered being on the ground.

Answer (score 5):

<sup>This question assumes that it's forbidden to enter certain parts of the Har Habayit nowadays, since we are all Ritually Unclean, which is how the Rambam paskens. For the record, the ראב"ד argues. (הלכות בית הבחירה פרק ו)</sup>

The Talmud [(שבועות יז.‏)](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01010.html#HtmpReportNum0030_L2) discusses the case of a Ritually Unclean person who hovers above the floor of the Mikdash. The Gemara remains unsure - תיקו - if the person is liable for punishment.

> בעי רבא **תלה עצמו באויר עזרה** מהו כי גמירי שהייה שהייה דבת השתחואה דלאו בת השתחואה לא גמירי או דלמא בפנים שהייה גמירי ל''ש דבת השתחואה ול''ש דלאו בת השתחואה **תיקו**

The Rambam remain unsure and doesn't decide this. [(הלכות שגגות י"א-ז'‏)](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_02002.html#HtmpReportNum0031_L2)

> וְכֵן אִם תָּלָה עַצְמוֹ בַּאֲוִיר עֲזָרָה. הַדָּבָר סָפֵק אִם אֲוִיר עֲזָרָה כַּעֲזָרָה אוֹ אֵינוֹ כַּעֲזָרָה:‏

The Tosafos [(שבועות י"ז. ד"ה תלה‏)](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01010.html#HtmpReportNum0030_L2) however *proves* that the air of the Mikdash must be like the Mikdash, since we have various halachot where a person's limbs are considered to be inside even though he's standing outside the Mikdash; so clearly the air of the Mikdash is also sanctified.

> **תלה עצמו באויר עזרה מה**ו. אית ספרים דגרסי אויר עזרה כעזרה דמי או לא וקשה דבפרק [כל הפסולין] (זבחים דף לב.) אמר **טמא שהכניס ידו לפנים חייב** דביאה במקצת שמה ביאה ובפרק כל הפסולין (שם דף לב:) נמי אמר ואי אמרת ביאה במקצת שמה ביאה היכי מעייל ידיה בבהונות **משמע דאויר נמי נתקדש** ועוד אי לאו כעזרה דמי א''כ כשמוליך דם ואיברים למזבח יפסל ביוצא ונראה כגירסת הספרים דגרסי כי גמירי שהייה היכא דבר השתחואה הוא:‏

The ראב"ד (father in law of his namesake above) in [(מסכת תמיד ל:‏)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=24225&st=%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%94%20&pgnum=24&hilite=) notes that the sanctity of any area that was open to the sky in the Mikdash, remains sanctified to the sky, even nowadays, even if there's a covering above it.

> כל מה שיעשה באויר העזרה שום דבר הכל קדוש  דלאו כל כמיני ע״י בניינו להפקיע קדושת העזרה שנתקדשה

<sup>Credit: The above is a loose translation of the relevant sections of [this web page](https://www.kikar.co.il/%D7%A0%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%98%D7%95%D7%A1-%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%9C-%D7%94%D7%A8-%D7%94%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA.html).</sup>

**Conclusion**: It's a מחלוקת of the ראשונים - an argument amongst early commentators - if it's forbidden to fly above the Mikdash area. Since this is a ספק דאורייתא - an uncertainty regarding a Torah matter - one needs to be stringent, it would seem. (And this is how Rav Ovadia Yosef זצ"ל decided in Yabia Omer (Yore Deah 5:26)   as [Baal Shemot Tovot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1172/baal-shemot-tovot) pointed out in the comments.)

Comment: I did not expect to find this directly addressed in the Talmud!